# Discord.py returning error: TypeError: 'TextChannel' object is not callable

Tags: python, discord

I've been writing a command in my Discord.py bot that is supposed to create a simple text channel. It does this just fine but returns this error:

```py
TypeError: 'TextChannel' object is not callable
```

Here's my code:

```py
@client.command(name="createchannel", aliases=['cc'])
async def create_channel(ctx, *, name):
create_channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(f"{name}")
  create_channel()
```

Comment: i think there's no need of `create_channel()` in that code, try without it

Comment: Perfect, this solution worked.